# Javascript password form with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

I've made a browser game which involves collecting clues. At the end, I have a page that asks the user to enter several characters in order to be redirected to another page. There are 13 boxes corresponding to the 13 letters in the last clue. So I've used a basic password entry form, removed the User ID part and replicated the password entry box with multiple conditions in the js code.

There should only be two acceptable inputs for each box (upper/lower case letters) and they all need to be correct in order to be redirected. Otherwise the user gets an error message. The Cancel button should just return the user to the previous page. Later on the password will be stored serverside, but for now it's fine to remain in the code.

It was sort of working earlier (I thought), but after adding the CSS and playing around with the appearance it has stopped working. Now it lets me go to the end page when I type anything into any number of boxes.

Note: I've spent several hours searching on SO for answers. I can't find any that match this problem exactly and I'm tearing my hair out! I'm new to javascript (and fairly new to coding full stop) so it's likely something basic that I'm missing.

Code below (I've included the code for the non-form bits in case any of that is messing with it)...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel="shorcut icon" href="cogfavicon.jpg" type="image/jpg">
    <link rel="icon" href="cogfavicon.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Works in Firefox/Chrome so far. Test with ipad...
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.toshow').fadeIn(2200);  // Fade in <div> on page load
    });

$(document).on("click", "a", function () {   // delegate all clicks on "a" tag (link)
var newUrl = $(this).attr("href");  // get the href attribute
if (!newUrl || newUrl[0] === "#") {  // verify if the new url exists or is a hash
    location.hash = newUrl;  // set that hash
    return;
}
$("html").fadeOut(function () {  // then fade out the page
    location = newUrl;  // when the animation completes, set the new location
});
return false;  // prevents the default browser behaviour stopping fade effect
}); 
</script>



<!-- Basic structure for blue door password -->
<body bgcolor="#000000">

<div id="wrapper" div class="toshow" style="display:none;"> <!-- div class added for fade in -->
    <div style="position:relative;top:25px;left:0px;z-index:-1">
    <img src="cogs.png" style="position:absolute" width="980" height="550" alt="Cogs" />
</div>

<div id="password" style="position:relative;top:130px;left:0px">
    <div style="position:relative;top:10px;left:36px">
    <h3>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; This door requires a code to unlock...<h3>
    <h1>L I K E &nbsp; &nbsp; C L O C K W O R K</h1>
    <form name="Blue Door Enter" style="position:relative;left:4px">
        <input type="password" name="pw1" style="width:19px"/>
        <input type="password" name="pw2" style="width:19px"/>
        <input type="password" name="pw3" style="width:19px"/>
        <input type="password" name="pw4" style="width:19px"/>
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input type="password" name="pw5" style="width:19px"/>
        <input type="password" name="pw6" style="width:19px"/>
        <input type="password" name="pw7" style="width:19px"/>
        <input type="password" name="pw8" style="width:19px"/>
        <input type="password" name="pw9" style="width:19px"/>
        <input type="password" name="pw10" style="width:19px"/>
        <input type="password" name="pw11" style="width:19px"/>
        <input type="password" name="pw12" style="width:19px"/>
        <input type="password" name="pw13" style="width:19px"/>
        <p><input type="button" style="position:relative;left:148px" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Enter"/>
        <input type="button" style="position:relative;left:148px" onclick="location.href='entranceroom.html';" value="Cancel"/></p>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
    function check(form) {  /* function to check PW */
        if((form.pw1.value === "C" || "c") && 
        (form.pw2.value === "H" || "h") &&
        (form.pw3.value === "R" || "r") &&
        (form.pw4.value === "I" || "i") &&
        (form.pw5.value === "S" || "s") &&
        (form.pw6.value === "T" || "t") &&
        (form.pw7.value === "M" || "m") &&
        (form.pw8.value === "A" || "a") &&
        (form.pw9.value === "S" || "s") &&
        (form.pw10.value === "S" || "s") &&
        (form.pw11.value === "N" || "n") &&
        (form.pw12.value === "O" || "o") &&
        (form.pw13.value === "W" || "w")) {  /* check if above values match */
            window.open("firstcorridor.html","_self");  /*open target page if they do */
        }
        else {
            alert("Incorrect") /* display error message */
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code...

```
/* main page components */
#wrapper {
    margin: 1px auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 980px;
    height: 650px; 
}
#enterbutton {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px;
    z-index: +1; 
}
#logo3bn {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px; 
}

#password{
    margin: 1px auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 490px;
    height: 325px; 
    color: #fff5f6;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: cambria math;
    font-size: large;
}
```

Comment: Please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/bgColor

Comment: Also, all it takes one to find the game clue is to simply read your page source and see the JS code...

Comment: Also, avoid inline `style`. Use `<style>`s instead!

Comment: Which is why the password will be stored server side eventually. Right now I'm just putting all the basics together. Although the intended users are about 7-9 years old, so I'm not sure they would even think to check. : )

Comment: Ok, thanks Roko. I wasn't aware of that, so will edit my code to match the newer syntax.

Comment: Than you should rather check your password server-side. Not browser-side. On  the browser side you should only validate if the user eventually has filled all the inputs. And instead of using `window.open` you can make a server-side redirect to the desired route...

Comment: It won't be on a server for several months yet and I haven't started looking at back end coding. I'm keeping everything on the front end for now.

Comment: Why are you using the `$(document).on("click", "a", function () {` yet you don't have a single `<a>` element in your HTML?

Comment: You have an unclosed `<h3>`...

Comment: What kind of attribute is `div` in `<div div class="toshow"`

Comment: Also, a suggestion is to avoid spaces inside name attributes...

Comment: There will be two additional buttons at the end of the page linked to other sites (I just haven't added these in yet).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the <div> attribute. This bit is to get the content to fade in on page load. I've had to trial and error using <div>s within <div>s to get it to look right.

Comment: I've updated the <h3> tag and changed the name attribute. Cheers!

Comment: What I meant is that you cannot have `div div` but only `div`. So it should be `<div class="toshow"`, not `<div div class="toshow"` or `<div div div div div  class="toshow"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the suggestions in the comments under your question.
Clean your HTML, close properly your tags, avoid inline styles and scripts.

Than, regarding your game, try something like the below.
This simple code can work for an indefinite number of forms - as long as you fill in the keys in the `keys` Object and their **value**s match the currently submitted **form ID**:

```js
var keys = {
  door_1: "q",
  door_2: "asd",
  // add more door keys here
}


$("form.door").on("submit", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault(); // Don't submit form

  // Get all clues as concatenated lowercase string:
  var clues = $(this).find(".clue").get().map(el => el.value).join("").toLowerCase();

  // Check if concatenated clues match the key value
  if ( clues === keys[ this.id ] ) {
    console.log("GOOD!!!");
  } else {
    console.log("BAD LUCK");
  }

});
```

```css
input.clue {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form class="door" id="door_1">
  <p>Enter <b>Q</b> upper or lowercase to enter this door</p>
  <input class="clue" maxlength=1 type=text>
  <button type="submit">ENTER</button>
</form>

<form class="door" id="door_2">
  <p>Enter <b>A S D</b> upper or lowercase to enter this door</p>
  <input class="clue" maxlength=1 type=text>
  <input class="clue" maxlength=1 type=text>
  <input class="clue" maxlength=1 type=text>
  <button type="submit">ENTER</button>
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: After a few days of experimentation, I've got a version of your original script above working great. I also gave in and set up a private server, set up a SQL database with password and I'm now in the process of trying to learn PHP very quickly so I can pull/check passwords in the database against the user input. But I'm using your code for other puzzles in the game, so it's very useful. Thank you again!